# How to validate and serialize recursive many to many relationship using Django REST framework in a most optimal way?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model CitizenInfo that contains a field 'relatives' with many to many relationship on itself. 
When i do a POST request what i want is to validate and deserialize the raw data from JSON using the optimal way.

What i found so far is a library for recursive model fields. https://github.com/heywbj/django-rest-framework-recursive and this not super informative topic https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/4183

This is my POST request:

```
[
        {
            "citizen_id": 1,
            "name": "Dave",
            "relatives": [2]
        },
        {
            "citizen_id": 2,
            "name": "Jack",
            "relatives": [1, 3]
        },
        {
            "citizen_id": 3,
            "name": "Alex",
            "relatives": [2]
        }
]
```

model.py:

```
class CitizenInfo(models.Model):
    citizen_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primal_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    relatives = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class CitizenInfoImportView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # Because of many=True we will use BulkCitizensSerializer
        serializer = CitizenListSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer_response = serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py

```
# Using this function for bulk_save operation
def save_citizens(citizen_data):

    new_citizen = CitizenInfo(citizen_id=citizen_data.get('citizen_id'),
                              name=citizen_data.get('name'))
    # Looping through relative list and do some custom serialization
    for relative in citizen_data.get('relatives'):
        pass
    return new_citizen


class BulkCitizensSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        new_citizens = [save_citizens(citizen_data) for citizen_data in validated_data]
        return CitizenInfo.objects.bulk_create(new_citizens)


class CitizenListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CitizenInfo
        field = '__all__'
        list_serializer_class = BulkCitizensSerializer
```

Also i had a limit that for one request it should be no more than 1000 relatives (2000 connected citizens). And i though that recursion is probably a bad way to solve it.

Any advice?

Comment: If the dataset is huge then you can try bulk create. I am seeing you have already written a serializer for that.

Comment: Yes, but what about validation of these field?  Custom validation by model is not working, error "pk doesn't exist" appear. I also want to validate input data, so for example if Dave have Jack as relatives - Jack should have Dave as well. And if this is not, then return "bad request 400"